# Bash script Set variable in loop

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run a for loop for all strings in a variable (one by one). When I echo my variable it is like this

```
A=(curl -s 'localhost:9200/something)
echo "$A"
```

emits:

```
sss
ddd
fff
ggg
hhh
```

My for loop is like this:

```
for i in "${A[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
  echo test
 done
```

But loop just run one time and print all data, instead of putting `test` after each item:

```
sss
ddd
fff
ggg
hhh
test
```

Comment: Try simple *echo $A | while read line; do echo $line; done*.

Comment: @0andriy thanks. it work like this: echo "$A" | while read line; do echo "$line"; done

Comment: `for i in $a; do echo "$i"; echo "test"; done`

Comment: Better store them in an **actual** array: `a=("sss" "ddd"); for i in "${a[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done`

Comment: @PesaThe I am running a command and the sending the output to A variable. A=(curl -s 'localhost:9200/something) . the output of this command print strings line by line. how I can send the output to array?

Comment: @hamidbayat In that case, use the `while read` solution. I wouldn't recommend @Cyrus' solution unless you turn off globbing with `set -f`.

Comment: @hamidbayat, how you're populating that variable is critical -- it's not actually an array when you assign it that way. The question is incomplete without that included inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @PresaThe,

```
while read line ; do  echo "$line" ; echo testsss; done <  <(curl -s 'localhost:9200/something)
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and within that the bullet point regarding questions which "*have already been asked and answered many times before*".